# Process Items in Javascript Constructor

Tags: javascript

I am creating a tree structure for a sidebar on a website. I want to pass in a title and then a list of items. If the item is a String or Number, it should be a normal list item. I also want to be able to pass in other lists so that there can be lists inside of other lists. How do I process the array I pass in? The following code doesn't work. I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#'.

```
function SidebarList(title, items = []) {
  this.title = title;
  this.items = [];
  for (let i in items) {
    if (typeof items[i] === String || typeof items[i] === Number) {
      this.items.push(new SidebarList(items[i]));
    } else {
      this.items.push(items[i]);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = SidebarList;
```

Comment: Don't use JavaScript for that, that's what document structure is for. You are reaching with your right hand for your left ear here. Seriously, is this homework or some fun exercise or something? Write a list in your document, style it, and you've got a side bar.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm grabbing the data from a database, so I have to dynamically display what I grab in a list.

Comment: Is the only problem that `module.exports = SidebarList;` throws an exception? If so, does `module.exports = function () {};` throw the same error? If so, the problem has nothing to do with sidebars, recursion, or constructors.

Comment: That shouldn't warrant a fancy model in JavaScript in order to build the markup fragment in the document. What's your data from database like? JSON? XML? CSV? I assume you are obtaining it client-side? Otherwise you could just generate the list (markup) as part of page generation on your Node.js instance (I assume it is).

Comment: In any case, yes, `module.exports = SidebarList` seems wrong, it should be `module.exports = { SidebarList }` or `module.exports.SidebarList = SidebarList`.

Comment: I wonder if it had something to do withi my usage of webpack. When I put `export default function SidebarList(title, items = [])`, it works.